# Should we encrypt data on our own if using SSL?

Tags: ssl, encryption, https

When we transfer our data over SSL, we are pretty sure that this data is not manipulated or read. But I have seen some programs installed on client and they are enabled to open SSL packets and show them. So a user will notice what we are sending and to which endpoint. The user then is able to repeat a request then which may cause some problems.

So Should we encrypt the data on our own a little maybe to harden this procedure or it is not that necessary ? Can we rely on SSL for security or we should add it some sugar?

Comment: No such program can succeed unless its certificate is trusted and either accepted by the applications or incorrectly ignored by those applications. Encryption over encryption is pointless if either encryption algorithm is secure and there are no other vulnerabilities in the system.

Comment: The entire point of sending the data to the client device is for the data to be read. If you add *another* layer of encryption, how would you decrypt the data on the client device?  And wouldn't any user who could see the unencrypted SSL stream also see this additional decryption?  If you don't trust the client machine with that data, don't send it - it's their machine, and if they want to, they're going to read the data.

Answer (score -1):

OpenSSL gives two forms of security:

- authentication through a third party guaranties that you are talking to the server you expect.
- encryption guaranties that the data you transmit between the two parties (i.e. client and server) can (ideally) not be decrypted and understood.

If you can see what you client is sending using packet analysers (e.g. tcpdump or wireshark) then it probably means your client is NOT sending encrypted packet and is NOT using SSL.

If you have openssl installed you can test the server by using the following command while tracking the packets:

openssl s_client -connect my.server.com:443

Note that I assume the SSL connection is established on port 443 (https).

You can then send data to the server by typing it on the command line and this should be encrypted. If you are dealing with a web server than you can type the GET command and it should return the webpage. Of course the received / sent data is decrypted on the terminal but it should be encrypted in the packets observed through wireshark/tcpdump.

Comment: I am sure I am connecting over https, But some programs like Fiddler, Packet Capture On Android , ... They install a certificate on your device and then are enabled to open https data. Not just my host but for most of websites using https I can see the data sent from my device !

Comment: *SSL* gives *three* forms of security.

Comment: @user207421 Right, I guess you mean it also guaranties data integrity in addition to confidentiality. Didnt.think of this one...
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/sy10670_.htm